# Почему падают тесты с Selenium 3.0? Ошибка "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium, test-automation, автоматизация

Тест запускает браузер и падает. Как это можно исправить?
Получаю такой лог:

```
  апр. 10, 2019 9:01:47 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1554919307747   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\foral\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.6FufIyO1gaL7"
1554919311010   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1554919311010   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1554919311010   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1554919318874   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 51757
 апр. 10, 2019 9:01:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
 INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
1554919319610   webdriver::command  WARN    You are using deprecated legacy session negotiation patterns (desiredCapabilities/requiredCapabilities), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities#Legacy
 апр. 10, 2019 9:01:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@37d4349f, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@37d4349f, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-KEPFHF1Q', ip: '172.21.2.78', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
at com.example.tests.Start.setUp(Start.java:19)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Тест:

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

 public class Start {org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.katalon.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testStart() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://srv-saumi-golf:18080/app");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Пользователь:'])[1]/following::td[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("f")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Пользователь:'])[1]/following::tr[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
        } else {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
        return alertText;
    } finally {
        acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Лучше воспользоваться Chromedriver, с ним автотесты запускаются.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Files\\chromedriver.exe");
```

2) Или попробовать добавить в класс:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Files\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.merge(dc);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```

3) Или попробовать использовать предыдущие версии Firefox, Selenium и geckodriver